# EclipseLink JPA secondary server

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

hoping someone may tell me if there is a way to provide automatic redundancy using JPA. We're currently using EclipseLink but can change should another provider have a suitable solution) and we need to ensure that we switch to our backup database should our primary database become unavailable (since its not located in the same building as our application). thanks for your input.

Comment: Are you using Spring? and which DB are you using?

Comment: @Augusto; no spring and mysql server (one primary, one backup), just need a quick solution to switch to backup should primary not be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the jdbc connection url as explained in the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). As an example

```
jdbc:mysql://master.server.com:3306,backup.server.com:3306/dbname
```

In this scenario, if maser.server.com fails, the driver will redirect the commands to backup.server.com. I strongly suggest you to read the whole documentation, as there are a lot of properties which change the failover behaviour, in particular the section *High Availability and Clustering.*

Comment: This is assuming backup.server.com has a backup of the database right? I guess a cluster?

Comment: @javy This works for active-passive clusters. The master is the active node and the passive is the backup node(s).

Comment: The only way is to have MySQL cluster or is there another free option?